# error 8 [failed second stage] with native error 16

Tags: symmetricds

i have installed `symmetricds` 3.7.23 version.
when i click on start server button.
I am getting the following error message.
error 8 [failed second stage] with native error 16.
please can any one tell me why i am getting this error?

Comment: Is there a stack trace in the log file?

Comment: hello boris.. thanks for your reply..yes there is a stack trace in . I am getting the following exception in wrapper file..Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/eclipse/jetty/server/SessionManager : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0...may i know why i am getting that exception

Comment: what's the java version on your machine? please run in command line `java -version`

Comment: java version 1.7.0_51

Comment: Hello Boris Pavlović..thanks for your advice.... working fine with java 8..but may i know why not with java 7...

Comment: create another question and delete this one

Comment: hello  Boris Pavlović. I created another question please reply me..thanks